# How to get specific featured image of every child page?

Tags: wordpress

Suppose I have inserted 3 featured image on my child pages(lets say, featured image 1, featured image 2, featured image 3). Now on my parent page, I need to query all of its child page with specific featured image. Lets say the query must get the featured image 2 only. Heres my code so far.

```
 <?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date')); ?> 
  <div id="child-list">
    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
      <div>
      <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?><br>
      <?php kd_mfi_the_featured_image('featured-image-2', 'page');
            echo get_post_meta($page->ID, 'featured-image-2', true); ?>
      </a>
      </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

It seems I'm having problem on

> kd_mfi_the_featured_image('featured-image-2', 'page'); 
>   echo get_post_meta($page->ID, 'featured-image-2', true);

but it works when I am previewing the child page, I could see the image 'featured-image-2' just changing $page-ID to get_the_ID(). Hope someone could give me an advice how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try

```
kd_mfi_the_featured_image('featured-image-2', 'page', 'full',  $page->ID  )
```

instead of

```
kd_mfi_the_featured_image('featured-image-2', 'page')
```

**edit:**

`kd_mfi_the_featured_image` returns value so you have to do `echo`

```
echo kd_mfi_the_featured_image('featured-image-2', 'page', 'full',  $page->ID  )
```

Comment: It really works, I just disregard the get_post_meta and BOOM! It shows the specific featured image. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: One more thing, what is the purpose of the 'full'?

Comment: it is a string to specify the image size you can use any of the wordpress defined sizes widths (thumbnail, medium, large or full)

Comment: or you can use array like this  array(32,32)  to specify the width and height. if this answer works for you can you make it as correct :)